# Get several values from the DB and put them in LIst

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have List with some names:

```
List<string> promoNames = new List<string>();
```

I need to get values ​​related to these names from `DB` with EF. 
I tried to do it with `for` loop, but I could not. Like that:

```
            PromoCode promos = null;
            for (var i = 0; i < _promoNames.Count; i++)
            {
                promos = await _mainDbContext.PromoCode.Where(prc => prc.Code == _promoNames[i]).SingleAsync();
                _promoJsonParams.Add(promos.JsonParams);
            }
```

How I can do it? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need loop. Just use `Contains` like this:

```
_mainDbContext.PromoCode.Where(prc => _promoNames.Contains(prc.Code)).Select (t=>t.JsonParams).ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

using Contains or IndexOf

```
promos = await _mainDbContext.PromoCode.Where(prc => _promoNames.Contains(prc.Code)).ToListAsync();
```

or

```
promos = await _mainDbContext.PromoCode.Where(prc => _promoNames.IndexOf(prc.Code) >= 0).ToListAsync();
```